# How to get the maximum and minimum number of length $m$ and the sum of the digits $s$

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

How to get the maximum and minimum of length $m$ and the sum of the digits $s$

By example:

Length: 2
Sum of its digits: 15

Max: 96,
Min: 69

Length: 2
Sum of its digits: 2

Max: 20,
Min: 11

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is for the maximum you need all the big numbers up front and for the minimum you need all the little numbers up front.  For the max, fill from the left with nines as far as they go, the remainder (if any) in the next digit, and finish with zeros.  For the min, fill from the right with nines, then the remainder, then zeros, saving a $1$ for the lead digit.

Comment: +1 and to have any solution, the sum of the digits must be at least $1$ and no more than $9$ times the number of digits.